# OnChange on a table is available in golang driver - rethinkDB?

Tags: go, drivers, rethinkdb

I am working on [RethinkDB](http://rethinkdb.com/) and [Golang](https://golang.org/) and completely new to these two `Technologies/Database`.

#### Note

GOLang driver - I am using [this](https://github.com/dancannon/gorethink) driver for connecting rethinkDB.

#### Problem

There is no `onChange` on a table functionality in this driver.

`Note` - [OnChange](http://rethinkdb.com/api/javascript/#changes) functionality is available in rethinkDB.

Any suggestion of golang driver which supports rethinkDB `onChange`.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry for the delayed reply I dont check StackOverflow as often as I should.

GoRethink actually does offer support for Changefeeds. Unfortunately the documentation is currently a bit lacking and I hope to work soon, until then I recommend having a look at the tests. Hopefully that should give you an idea on how to use them.

https://github.com/dancannon/gorethink/blob/master/query_table_test.go#L215

If you have any further questions regarding change feeds or any other issues with the driver let me know.

Answer (score -2):

That `Go` driver is provided by a third party and as you note they do not seem to have yet added support for changefeeds. It is hosted on GitHub, so you could file an [enhancement request](https://github.com/dancannon/gorethink/issues). There is recent activity in their repository, so there is hope that they will add it.

Comment: Author commented above, this answer needs updating.